# Insert text into the textbox in qwebview through virtual keyboard

Tags: qt, qwebview

I am developing a virtual keyboard in qt. I want to display it in QWebView when user taps on a text field in web page. I am able to pop up the kayboard on user click. But not able to put the text into the text field entered through virtual keyboard. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?
The idea is to connect your keyboard to a customized slot that would convert data to a format supported by the QWebView. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you have, which approaches did you try?

A simple way would be to inject a fake QKeyEvent into Qt's eventing system, using QCoreApplication::postEvent()